# Issues with HTML5 'required' and jQuery validator

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm working on a poc wherein I'm using `required` attribute for a couple of text fields and jQuery validator for another field (not a mandatory field but added a custom validation to it). Below is the fiddle for the same.

POC **https://jsfiddle.net/rkLpovda/1/**

What I'm expecting is...

1. When nothing is provided, when I click on Submit button, it should
   an show error for the first two text fields - O/p: Working as expected.
   No issues
2. When an input is supplied to the last text field (custom validation)
   and user clicks on submit button, if the validation fails, I'm expecting all the three text fields to throw an error - O/P : Unfortunately, only the last one is getting triggered.

Why is `required` failed to throw an error when custom validation pops-in? Please share your thoughts.

**Update:** I just noticed that once the error appears for last text field and if I click on submit button again, then I can see the errors for all text fields.

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css`, `js` at Question?

Comment: why have you not added required in last field?

Comment: Did u include jquery-1.10.0.min.js
jquery.validate.min.js in your project

Comment: Fiddle included in the message. https://jsfiddle.net/rkLpovda/1/

Comment: @DharaParmar It's not a required field

Comment: @Anbarasi Yes, I did.

Comment: @sriram ... ok so if user enter anything in last field then only validations need to be checked..right?

Comment: @Dhara Parmar True. It has to trigger the custom validation which I included.

Comment: for 2nd point  if the validation fails, first page will call the custom field validation so it will call onblur event, so if you first blur input and then click submit button your functionality will work fine @Sriram

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("validatePossibleYear", function(value, element) {
      var currYear = new Date().getFullYear();
     $("#fName").blur(); $("#lName").blur();
      return !( value != "" && !(value == currYear || value == currYear - 1));   
      },
    "Invalid Year. It should be either current year or previous year"
  );
});
  $('#validateTest').validate({
    rules: {
      pYear: {
      required:true,
        validatePossibleYear : true
      }
    },
     submitHandler: function(form) 
             {
                form.submit();
             }
  });
```

Comment: @sriram  what  2 things ??

Comment: Thanks @Shalini for the response. However as mentioned in my post, pYear is not a required field. I could not see what I was expecting.

Comment: remove required ..i tried on at my end ,When an input is supplied to the last text field (custom validation) and user clicks on submit button, if the validation fails, all the three text fields to throw an error

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Wondering how you were able to see all three at once.